# How to get the result in the form of anchor tags in php

Tags: php

Hello i am beginner to PHP.I am not getting an idea regarding how to get  all the rows as an output in the form of anchor tags .Here is my following code where blogtable is the name of the table . For instance i have five rows in a table . I want the entire rows as links as a resultant.By executing the following code i am getting the records in a table but unable to transform these results into anchor tags.Kindly suggest me an idea to get each and every row in the form of anchor tag.Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("test");
$data = mysql_query("select * from blogtable");

while ($col = mysql_fetch_field($data)) {
    echo $col->name;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($data)) {

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($row); $i++) {
        echo"<br/>";
        echo"$row[$i]></a>";
        echo"<br/>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: **Note:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `echo "<a href=\"".$row[$i]."\">".$row[$i]."</a>";`

Comment: You said this for my answer too - there is **no** syntax error here.

Comment: Thank you so much Gimmy it worked can i redirect this links to another php script using php or shall i use javascript?Kindly suggest me an idea

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for. You want to redirect the dinamicaly generated link? Give me an example please.

Answer (score 2):

Just add your link inside the `for` loop:

```
echo "<a href='http://example.com'>" . $row[$i] . "</a>";
```

Comment: Hello Danny Beckett suppose i have a row in a table for instance abc i need abc as a link in output kindly suggest me thank you

Comment: Would `echo "<a href='" . $row[$i] . "'>" . $row[$i] . "</a>";` work?

Comment: No Danny It is showing syntax error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in C:\wamp\www\result.php on line 17.

Comment: @shashank There's nothing wrong with that code. There is no syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo"$row[$i]></a>;
```

This is not the correct syntax for an anchor tag. Try something like:

```
 echo "<a href='some site'>$row[$i]</a>";
```